# Retrieving additional properties through RadComboBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, radcombobox

I used to use the ComponentArt controls way back in the day and you could specify whether you want additional fields to be bound to each item in the ComboBox.

I am wondering if I can do something similar with the RadComboBox.

For example here is how I am binding it:

```
    IEnumerable<State> stateList = StateService.GetStates();
    cbState.DataValueField = "Id";
    cbState.DataTextField = "Name";
    cbState.DataSource = stateList;
    cbState.DataBind();
```

How can I also access additional State properties from the SelectedItem since the DataSource is an object list of type State?

Comment: what does the class State look like? Is there a specific attribute you need access to? Have you tried using Custom Attributes?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-custom-attributes.html

RadComboBox items provide a special collection called Attributes. You can use this collection to expand the information stored with the items. The Attributes collection lets you store any number of attributes as name / value pairs. You can specify custom attributes declaratively in the RadComboBoxItem tag or programmatically using the Attributes collection of the RadComboBoxItem.